# Что с моей флешкой?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, железо

Купил USB 3.0 флешку `SanDisk Ultra 16Гб`. В отзывах пишут, что сделана на очень редком чипе `PHISON PS2303`.
У меня в `Ubuntu 17.10` не работает. Что с ней?

**dmesg**

```
[14179.720020] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[14179.874280] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5581
[14179.874284] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[14179.874286] usb 1-6: Product: Ultra
[14179.874288] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[14179.874289] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 4C530001220927106095
[14179.877937] usb-storage 1-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[14179.881008] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-6:1.0
[14180.913197] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Ultra            1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[14180.916211] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[14180.916941] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] 30629376 512-byte logical blocks: (15.7 GB/14.6 GiB)
[14180.918316] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] Write Protect is off
[14180.918321] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[14180.919581] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[14180.946601]  sdg: sdg1
[14180.955192] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI removable disk

[14212.598340] usb 1-6: reset high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[14217.962706] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[14233.579781] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[14233.807796] usb 1-6: reset high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[14233.939809] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[14234.179819] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[14234.407836] usb 1-6: reset high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[14234.823858] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 10, error -71
[14234.943868] usb 1-6: reset high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[14235.367898] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 10, error -71
[14235.367989] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 10
[14235.383947] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[14235.383955] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdg] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 d3 5d 80 00 00 08 00
[14235.383959] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdg, sector 30629248
[14235.481894] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: port 6 reset error -110
[14236.767988] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using uhci_hcd
[14236.896019] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[14237.132013] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[14237.360096] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 8 using uhci_hcd
[14237.488047] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[14237.724073] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[14237.952089] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using uhci_hcd
[14238.368110] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 9, error -71
[14238.488141] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 10 using uhci_hcd
[14238.904143] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 10, error -71
[14238.904184] usb usb4-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Comment: На винде пробовал? Всё ок? А то строка `I/O error` как-то смущает.